# Remote Docker daemon with public access from any client?

Tags: docker

Docker has a relatively coherent guide regarding running a docker daemon with remote access over HTTPS: https://docs.docker.com/articles/https/

What it does not address, is, how can the daemon be exposed so that clients of varying hosts may access it, rather than just one static known-before-hand host?

The first use-case is that I want to use/try/test stuff against the daemon from my local machine. I expect that sooner or later different production hosts will also use the daemon such as if our organization decides to use (or trial run) different build systems that have to interact with the daemon (which is what we are going to do with CircleCI as it builds our projects).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not limited to one host.

Follow the instructions, then copy the certificate to each client that will connect.

Comment: Thanks, I see that I misunderstood. The CN for the key being used on the server must have the correct host but the client key/cert is free from such limitation. I was unable to get client-verification to work but that is a separate TLS issue from this one.